# What checksum does Docker use for caching COPY?

Tags: caching, docker, checksum

I am trying to debug a Docker cache issue and I want to check if the cache should match.

```
Step 7 : COPY myfile /home/me/myfile
 ---> daa0799b47df
```

What does the above ID represent? It doesn't seem to be part of a md5 or sha1 checksum. Can I run a command to check this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is random bytes, hex encoded. This is the short form returned by https://github.com/moby/moby/blob/0eefae8e0db0c3c567e8807f09434a0da3fc1261/utils/utils.go#L171 and generated by https://github.com/moby/moby/blob/0eefae8e0db0c3c567e8807f09434a0da3fc1261/utils/utils.go#L180. It is not a checksum and once again is random. It is simply used to identify images and containers.

Comment: so yeah it's the COPY layer digest that's printed, and not the checksum that Docker computes from the file

Comment: This is true for Docker 1.9 and below

Answer (score 0):

Docker [1.10+ introduced ID's based on secure content hashes](https://web.archive.org/web/20160219002754/https://blog.docker.com/2016/01/docker-1-10-rc/).

A hash is generated for the contents of each file system layer, then a hash is generated for the image descriptor as well. If any component to the image changes, the hash changes.

Comment: That link is no longer working.